# Is the Airtel music ad the most streamed song and most downloaded ringtone?

Tags: india, music, internet

[This image](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2512/37582) was forwarded to me on Whatsapp

[image]

> The Airtel Music Ad composed by A R Rahman was the Most Streamed Song in the World in the Year 2005-2009. Also it is the Most Downloaded Ringtone in the World all time. Most Amazing Fact about this Airtel Ad is - It is the First Video uploaded on YouTube in India on October 13 2006.

Are these claims true?

Comment: I'm conflicted: I have never heard of it, but I don't want to listen to it on youtube as I'll just make this claim more likely :-)

Comment: For those who care: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuAe2lziMqI  (I don't know that I've ever heard it.)